How do I investigate a .NET MAUI control binding issue
I have a DateControl to display, select, or clear a date value. It has three components: an Entry field that displays the date; a calendar image button to select a new date via a popup; and a clear image button to clear the date value.

The control has a DateValue bindable property of type DateTime defined as follows.
    public static readonly BindableProperty DateValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(DateValue),
        returnType: typeof(DateTime),
        declaringType: typeof(DateControl),
        defaultValue: DateTime.Now,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public DateTime DateValue
    {
        get { return (DateTime)base.GetValue(DateValueProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(DateValueProperty, value); }
    }

The DateValue property is linked to the Entry field having been converted to a string.
I then have two views that use the DateControl. The XAML code and bound view model properties are defined as follows where the converter is from the Community Toolkit.
First:
<controls:DateControl x:Name="dateFilter"
    DateValue="{Binding DateFilter, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeOffsetConverter}}"

[ObservableProperty] 
private DateTimeOffset _dateFilter = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;

Second:
<controls:DateControl x:Name="dateField" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
    DateValue="{Binding JournalDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeOffsetConverter}}"

[ObservableProperty] 
private DateTimeOffset _journalDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;

The DateFilter property in the first is updated whenever the DateControl value changes. However, the JournalDate property in the second never gets modified when the DateControl value changes.
I have reviewed the code for differences and debugged through both. I have tried the same and various different date values. I have temporarily added property changing/changed handlers to try and locate the reason without success.

Your demand is that when the date in the first DateControl is modified, the date in the second DateControl is updated synchronously, right?

No. The first and second snippets are from two different view models both using the same control. The view model property in the first snippet works as expected - that is its value is reflected and reflects whatever is in the DateControl that it is bound to. I wish to know why the second snippet that uses the same control and appears identical never receives any changes made in the control.

According to the code you provided, the cause of the problem could be due to DateFilter, JournalDate or converter, could you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to help community to reproduce your problem?

Trying to produce an MRE spotted that the static resource for the second converter was not defined and was causing the issue. For some reason, I had all converters except this one defined in App.xaml. The XAML for the first view had a local resource definition hence why it was working. Doh.

So defining a static resource for the second converter solved the problem?
